# install turtlesim

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install groovy on ArchLinux (ARM7) on Odroid-X.
And I haven't (for example) turlesim (and more packages).
How to install the packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110131/install-turtlesim/) by [Ruslan](https://answers.ros.org/users/9866/ruslan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should install [yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/yaourt) (or [packer](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/packer/)). Then, you would simply have to type (for instance):

```
yaourt --noconfirm ros-groovy-turtlesim
```

Not all the packages are available in AUR (this is a lengthy process and there are few maintainers), but the most important ones are. You can see the list of available Groovy packages [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&C=0&SeB=nd&K=ros-groovy&outdated=&SB=n&SO=a&PP=200).

As @Ruslan pointed out, all the instructions are available [here](http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Arch#Method_1:_Using_the_AUR_Packages). By using AUR packages, you will be sure that no conflict happens when installing packages, and dependencies will be automatically checked/installed. This is not necessarily the case if you are installing from source on your own. Also, when installing from source, you will probably end up with Python2/Python3 conflicts that are automatically fixed in AUR packages.

If you encounter a problem with one of the packages, leave a message on the adequate AUR package page and/or contact the maintainer.

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1